# $11$th grade problem equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't solve an equation, I tried using different methods, but I can't succeed. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Please help me, this is the equation: $x^4+2x^3+5x^2+4x-5=0$.

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I tried to group them by x^4+x^3+x^3+5x+5x+4x - 5 = 0 but did not got me a good answer, and probably that's a bad method.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E4+%2B+2x%5E3+%2B+5+x%5E2+%2B+4x+-+5+) you can factor it as $(x^2 + x - 1) (x^2 + x + 5)$

Comment: I tried this also, but this method does not let me solve this. 
I tried to do (x+a/2+y)^2 - [ (a^2/4 + 26 - 5)*x^2 + (ay -c)*x + (y^2 -d ) ] = 0
Where a = 2; b=5; c=4; d=-5.
After i got (X^2+1+y)^2 - [(2y-4)x^2 - (2y-4)*x + (y^2 +5) ] = 0;
After i calculated discriminant by:

(2y+4)^2 - 4* (2y-4) * (Y^2 + 5)

and got
4y^2 + 16y + 16 - 8y^3 - 40y^2 + 16y^2 + 80 = 0 
After that i got
-8y^3 - 20y^2 + 16y + 96 = 0 i divided by -4
and got:
(2y^3 + 5y^2) - (4y-24) = 0 ; and i got stuck here.

Comment: @iftwMZ: If you have the factorization then you can solve two *quadratic* equations separately.

Comment: See Wolfram Alpha's [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E4%2B2x%5E3%2B5x%5E2%2B4x-5%3D0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I let $f(x)$ be your polynomial.  One trick that sometimes helps is to look at $f(x + a)$ for some small values of $a$.   I did that, and not much popped up.  Then I tried $f(a-x)$ for some small values of $a$ and when I simplified $f(-1-x)$  I got $f(x)$ back.  So the polynomial is symmetric about $a/2 = -1/2$.  Aha.

So then I simplified $f(x-1/2)$ and got

$$x^4 +\frac{7}{2}x^2 - \frac{95}{16}.$$

Multiplying the equation through by $16$ gives

$$16x^4+56x^2- 95 = 0.$$

And that guy factors as

$$(4x^2-5)(4x^2+19)=0.$$